# Saving to an xml file - unterminated entity reference error

Tags: php

I'm trying to save text to an xml file but if I use certain characters  like for example the "**&**" symbol... I get the following error (*below*)

```
Warning: main(): unterminated entity reference
```

What's the deal with this? If anyone could help, I would really appreciate it!

**Here is my code:**

```
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
    function magicQuotes_awStripslashes(&$value, $key) {$value = stripslashes($value);}
    $gpc = array(&$_GET, &$_POST, &$_COOKIE, &$_REQUEST);
    array_walk_recursive($gpc, 'magicQuotes_awStripslashes');
}



$new_input = $_POST['userInput']; 
// echo $new_input;

$doc = new DOMDocument( );

$edit = $doc->createElement( 'edit' );
$edit->nodeValue = $new_input;

$doc->appendChild($edit);
$doc->save('../text.xml');
```

Comment: try escaping that XML entity character `&amp;` with [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't muck about setting an element's nodeValue directly with arbitrary text. Create a new [text node](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domtext.php) and append it. E.g.:

```
$edit->appendChild(new DOMText($new_input));
```

Comment: Worked perfect! Thanks buddy!